# Using generics, how can I create a tuple of objects from a captured array?

Tags: typescript, generics, strong-typing

Given a function like this:

```
function makeObjects<T extends string[]>(...values: T);
```

Make the return value this:

```
T.map(v => ({ [v]: any }));
```

I'm using an array map to show what it looks like in my mind, yes I know that's not how TS works.

Comment: Is... [this](https://tsplay.dev/WoGbPW) what you're looking for? If not, please consider clarifying your requirement, perhaps with some more words describing it, and some input-output examples.  Right now you are using nonstandard/pseudo code and so I'm just guessing.

Comment: @jcalz this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd give it the following call signature:

```
declare function makeObjects<T extends string[]>(...values: T):
  { [I in keyof T]: { [P in Extract<T[I], string>]: any } };
```

( Note that I have not implemented `makeObjects()`, and consider this to be outside the scope of the question as asked ).

---

The return type `{[I in keyof T]: ...}` is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over the keys of the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) input type parameter `T`.  When `T` is an array or tuple type, the output type [will also be an array or tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays).

For each numeric-like index `I` from the input array type `T`, we want to use the element type `T[I]` as a key type.  For this you need to use another mapped type, conceptually like `{[P in T[I]]: any}`, which means "an object type whose keys are `T[I]` and whose values are `any`".  You could also express this as `Record<T[I], any>` using [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype).

Unfortunately while you only care about numeric-like indices, the compiler takes the view that `I` could be *any* key of `T`, including the array method names like `"push"` and `"pop"`, and thus the property type `T[I]` could be all kinds of things you don't want to use as keys.  (See [ms/TS#27995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27995) for a discussion of this issue).

The way to deal with that is to wrap `T[I]` in something the compiler will agree is definitely key-like.  Since you only care about `T[I]` being a `string` (since `T extends string[]`), we can use [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to filter `T[I]` to just string-like things.

So that gives you `{ [I in keyof T]: { [P in Extract<T[I], string>]: any }}`.

---

Let's test it out:

```
const foo = makeObjects("a", "b", "c");
// const foo: [{  a: any; }, { b: any; }, { c: any; }]
```

Looks good; the output type is a tuple of objects whose keys come from the corresponding parameter to `makeObjects()`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwFsoBrEAeQCMArcDAZwB4AVeEADwxFWDvjoxhZUAcwDaAXQB8ACgB08gG5QIyEHQBc8JgEp1AKHjwA3vFEBJeEPikAnjkRbxmk6IAKl-AFEOMKJmbm4gA0fAJCwpJO8FCoNvAAvgkA3Hp6YHj8SDg48AC8hCTk1LR00gBEUGUhZRRV8GVgZdopAPQt8OmomYjZmqIm0ZoxNkkJISYUQ7Gj8eMdUyMJ4vBAA)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mapped type `Record` to create a type from the values in `T`:

```
function makeObject<T extends string[]>(...values: T): Record<T[number], any>{
    return null!
}

let x = makeObject("a", "b", "c")

x.a
x.d // err
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIYGsCmB5ARgK02gB4AVRTADykzABMBnRBqAJxjAHMBtAXQD4AFADpRAN1QAbEJgYAuRKQCUCgEpE4rOmW5gQyXJla8ANIlRgAnvwDeAKESPErTFBCskeyZICEdgL52dpKuiJSIALwoGDgERFCCAESoiWaJuKmIiRCJSkGUwqh2BXSIAPRlFKysdkA)

Comment: Yeah this could be what OP wants (especially given the name `makeObject`), but "tuple of objects" in the title makes me think it might be what I put in my comment.  Not sure, though.

Comment: I made a mistake when writing the code example, It should say "makeObjects" the thing I want is a tuple of objects mapped by the array.